# How to export roughness, specular, metallic maps from Blender to UE4 through FBX

Tags: unreal-engine4

In Blender 2.93 and 3.0,

It seems that roughness can not be exported through FBX to Unreal 4.26

See relative video of a guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtPYTaCcCNU

Answer (score 0):

Blender -> FBX -> UE4

Roughness becomes metallic;

Specular becomes Roughness;

Metallic is lost;

[image]

[image]